# Regex - how to get windows service state in Java?

Tags: java, regex

When running the command `sc query <serviceName>`, the next output is getting back:

```
TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

How can I extract the service state (in this case is *RUNNING*) using regex with Java?

Comment: Please specify a language or tool in which you are able to run Regular Expressions from.

Comment: Try `(?m)^\s*STATE\b.*?(\S+)$` then access to first capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match:

- `\b` a word boundary
- the word STATE followed by
- one or more whitespace characters `\s+`
- one `\d` or one or more digits `\d+`
- one or more whitespace characters `\s+`
- Capture in a group (group 1) one or more non-whitespace characters `(\S+)` which in this case will be `RUNNING`

[`\bSTATE\s+:\s+\d+\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/6xvzXE/1)

In Java

`\\bSTATE\\s+:\\s+\\d+\\s+(\\S+)`

[Test](http://rextester.com/PPSG1717)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below regex

```
(.*?STATE\s*:\s*\d*\s*)(\w+)
```

and match group 2. See this link [Regex Solution](https://regex101.com/r/7o625K/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
STATE.*?(\S+)\n
```

The matched group should be *RUNNING*. You can see details and example [here](https://regex101.com/r/g4i5rN/1).

The important part is the use of a lazy star operator `*?` that allows matching the whole word at the end of the line instead of a single letter.

P.S: depending on whether you match multiline regex or not, you might want to switch the `\n` for a `$`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to quickly get this value using `.replaceFirst()`:

```
String result = s.replaceFirst("(?s).*?STATE[\\d\\s:]*(\\w+).*", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10t84V/2). Since the string is always in this format, and is not that long, this approach is quite convenient to implement in Java.

See the [online Java demo](http://rextester.com/MULC78971).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier making `.` match any char including line break chars
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `STATE` - substring `STATE`
- `[\d\s:]*` - 0+ digits, whitespaces and `:`
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (what we want to keep, later, we can refer to the value using `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern): 1+ word chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (up to the string end).